# The identification of vector and a matrix ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The elements of $K^n$ are vectors $ \left( x_{1}, ....... , x_{1} \right)$

and this element is matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\.\\.\\.\\x_{n}\end{bmatrix}
\ \in M_{n*1}(K) $ ,I  can't see why they are equal ? why do they mean the same thing ?

Comment: The column matrix is a way of **representing** vectors, just as matrices are a way of representing linear maps.

Comment: Any $m\times n$ matrix can be thought of as a representation of a $m\cdot n$-dimensional vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not equal.  Vector can be REPRESENTED as $1 \times n$ matrices or as $n \times 1 $ matrices. In other words, $K^n$ is isomorphic to $M_{1\times n}(K)$ and also to $M_{n \times 1}(K)$.

Comment: @user161440 It is a common practice in Mathematics to identify isomosphic vector spaces. As vector spaces, they are indistinguishable.